# how to split xml root into two branches - with all but a specific child in the first branch and the specific child in the second

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, transformation

The problem is similar to my previous one. This time I have a file:

```
<config width="100" height="200">
    <parameter name="account number" country="UK">
        12345678901234567890123456
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="client code" codeType="xa">
        UK0112
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="email-address" accepts="yes">
        john.sparrow@rex.co.uk
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="postal-code" country="UK">
        W1A 1HQ
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="additional parameters" mode="on">
        <parameter name="preferences" type="internal">
            Not applicable
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="issues" type="internal">
            None
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="complaints" type="internal">
            None
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="approbation" type="external">
            X11
        </parameter>
    </parameter>
</config>
```

This time I want to disentangle one arbitrary child with the name "issues" and put it into separate branch, like this

```
<configs>
    <config width="100" height="200">
        <parameter name="account number" country="UK">
            12345678901234567890123456
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="client code" codeType="xa">
            UK0112
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="email-address" accepts="yes">
            john.sparrow@rex.co.uk
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="postal-code" country="UK">
            W1A 1HQ
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="additional parameters" mode="on">
            <parameter name="preferences" type="internal">
                Not applicable
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="complaints" type="internal">
                None
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="approbation" type="external">
                X11
            </parameter>
        </parameter>
    </config>
    <config width="100" height="200">
        <parameter name="issues" type="internal">
                None
        </parameter>
    </config>
<configs>
```

The choice of the child and its parent is hard coded (parameter/parameter) and based on attribute name (issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <configs>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <config width="{@width}" height="{@height}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/parameter[@name = 'issues']"/>
      </config>
    </configs>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parameter[@name = 'additional parameters']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="@*|node()[not(self::parameter[@name = 'issues'])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the provided XML:**

```
<config width="100" height="200">
  <parameter name="account number" country="UK">
        12345678901234567890123456
    </parameter>
  <parameter name="client code" codeType="xa">
        UK0112
    </parameter>
  <parameter name="email-address" accepts="yes">
        john.sparrow@rex.co.uk
    </parameter>
  <parameter name="postal-code" country="UK">
        W1A 1HQ
    </parameter>
  <parameter name="additional parameters" mode="on">
    <parameter name="preferences" type="internal">
            Not applicable
        </parameter>
    <parameter name="issues" type="internal">
            None
        </parameter>
    <parameter name="complaints" type="internal">
            None
        </parameter>
    <parameter name="approbation" type="external">
            X11
        </parameter>
  </parameter>
</config>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<configs>
  <config width="100" height="200">
    <parameter name="account number" country="UK">
        12345678901234567890123456
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="client code" codeType="xa">
        UK0112
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="email-address" accepts="yes">
        john.sparrow@rex.co.uk
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="postal-code" country="UK">
        W1A 1HQ
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="additional parameters" mode="on">
      <parameter name="preferences" type="internal">
            Not applicable
        </parameter>
      <parameter name="complaints" type="internal">
            None
        </parameter>
      <parameter name="approbation" type="external">
            X11
        </parameter>
    </parameter>
  </config>
  <config width="100" height="200">
    <parameter name="issues" type="internal">
            None
        </parameter>
  </config>
</configs>
```

---

**EDIT: the OP has suggested that the newly created `<config>` element that contains `<parameter name="issues" type="internal">` should copy *all* attributes from the original `<config>` element.**

In this case, one should simply change:

```
<config width="{@width}" height="{@height}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*/parameter[@name = 'issues']"/>
</config>
```

...to:

```
<config>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*/parameter[@name = 'issues']"/>
</config>
```

...which means the new solution in it's entirety would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <configs>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <config>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*/parameter[@name = 'issues']"/>
      </config>
    </configs>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parameter[@name = 'additional parameters']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="@*|node()[not(self::parameter[@name = 'issues'])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hmm... but you hardcoded attributes of config, namely width="{@width}" height="{@height}"
What if I had other attributes (they would not then be transferred )

Comment: @Marcin - That isn't "hardcoding". You did not specify where those values should come from, so I made the assumption that they should equal the identical parameters in the root node. If you require something different, you need to explicitly say what it is (and not leave us to guess).

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry..., the xslt file should transform all of the attributes which will (probably) occur in xml nodes - if they occur. The only assumption is: the name attributes will always be present. All the attributes (apart from name) are provided only as an example.

Comment: "All of the attributes which will (probably) occur in xml nodes" is, unfortunately, not very clear. I've updated my answer with what I *think* you're looking for. If that isn't true, please update the original question with as much detail as you can provide.

Comment: Yes - that is exactly what I thought of. Thanks very much. 
Each and every additional attribute I can think of is now properly transferred where it should go.